# Success/Error message not showing up in Magento version 2.3.6-p1 while login, registration and subscription

Tags: success-message, error-message, login-register, magento2.3.6-p1

I installed a fresh Magento instance and noticed there are no messages (error/success) is showing up while a new customer registration, login with wrong email/password, submit mail to the subscription list, etc.

In my findings, Magento generates `mage-messages` cookie which is responsible for holding the session message but the problem is Magento generates two same-name cookies `mage-messages` where the first one has the message but the second has an empty value. Any workaround over there? Thank You.

Comment: what is your base url and the cookie domain you set for this installation?

Comment: @DianaBotean http://127.0.0.1/mage236p1/ is the base URL. I did not set any cookie domain explicitly. Is it required to set a cookie domain? Thank You for your reply.

Comment: no, not necessarily. it's more like when you are using subdomains and have multiple instances of magento on the domain, this is how i asked about the format of the base url.

Comment: are your caches on or off?

Comment: Yes, Cache is enabled.

Comment: ok. this looks indeed farfetched, but i read at some point about a similar problem, 'solved' by enabling caches. so had to ask :)

Comment: It could be a bug for Magento 2.3.6-p1. Because I tested the same to same use-cases on other versions. Unfortunately, I found the problem only with this version.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem @MilanChandro

Comment: @Gulshan Yes, The issue was fixed after using a virtual host or domain name.

Comment: I am using domain name and still getting same issue

Comment: @Gulshan  For domain name, you may change the following options `Stores > Configuration > Web > Default Cookie Settings > Cookie Path | Cookie Domain` and flush the cache.